# Why are parameter based definitions more efficient than recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a recursive function sumdown :: Int -> Int that returns the sum of
all natural numbers from its argument down to zero e.g. sumdown 3 should return the sum 3+2+1+0 = 6.

```
sumdown :: Int -> Int
sumdown 0 = 0
sumdown x = x + sumdown(x-1)
```

I also have this definition which I dont fully understand, could someone please evaluate this for me and tell me why its potentially more efficient than the definition above?

```
sumdown n = sumd n 0
sumd 0 a = a
sumd n a = sumd (n-1) (n+a)
```

Thanks.

Comment: That `a` is in fact an accumulator and helps to make the recursion a tail call optimized one. Which means unlike in the first example, it doesn't grow the call stack.

Comment: @Redu Haskell doesn't have a call stack, it has a thunk stack. Blindly getting things into tail recursive form can actually hurt performance of Haskell programs, since using an accumulator inherently interferes with laziness by preventing the function from returning until it's inspected the entire input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first recursion sums values `[0..n]` starting from its end (`n`), like this:

```
1+(2+(3+(... + ((n-1) + n)) ...)))
```

With this approach, the program first has to enumerate all the numbers, generating the full sequence, and only after that additions can actually be performed.

This requires O(n) memory and O(n) time.

In the second recursion, we count from `0` to `n` as we did earlier, but now we sum numbers as we go, like in

```
(((1+2)+3)+4)+ ...
```

We can sum `1+2` before we count up to `3`. After that, we can keep only the result of the previous sum `1+2`, and discard the numbers `1` and `2` from memory. Hence, in the whole process we only keep in memory 1) the result of the sum of the numbers met so far, and 2) the next number in the sequence.

Hence, we now require only O(1) memory and O(n) time.

Note: since Haskell is lazy, the above argument holds only if the partial sum is actually forced at every recursion. This forcing might be silently added by the compiler optimizer, but it's a good idea to be explicit about it, e.g. in

```
sumdown n = sumd n 0
sumd 0 !a = a
sumd n !a = sumd (n-1) (n+a)
-- here I am using the BangPatterns extension,
-- otherwise, seq can be used instead
```

The second recursion is usually called "accumulator-style", which is a specific case of "tail recursion".

(Note 2: tail recursion is not always a good idea in a lazy language like Haskell, but if the data passed around is simple, e.g. like numbers and not like lists, tail recursion is usually beneficial.)

Comment: It's worth note that using O(n) memory over O(n) allocations will result in O(n^2) work being done in garbage collection if the process goes long enough and dominates memory use for the program.

Answer (score 5):

The second function is tail-recursive, the reason it performs better is clearly visible if you follow the reduction steps. (Although due to the lazy nature of Haskell, the following is not purely correct, but it gives an idea of how tail recursive functions can be more efficient.)

```
sumdown 3
// 3 + sumdown 2
// 3 + (2 + sumdown 1)
// 3 + (2 + (1 + sumdown 0)
// 3 + (2 + (1 + 0))
// 3 + (2 + 1)
// 3 + 3
// 6


sumdown 3 0
// sumdown 2 3
// sumdown 1 5
// sumdown 0 6
// 6
```

Additionally in most languages, the tail-recursive code is optimized to reuse the same stack (as it is the last operation of the recursive function).

Comment: I think your comment about “reusing the same stack” is true but misleading—it’s not like in a strict language where the call is optimised into a jump, but rather, each recursive call only generates one frame on the *thunk* evaluation stack before returning, assuming the accumulator is strict. In pseudo-STG: `0 3 sumd force` → `3 2 sumd force` → `5 1 sumd force` → `6 0 sumd force` → `6`.

Comment: @JonPurdy yes you are right. I didn't want to go in that detail. I fixed my wording :)